# How to use a DELETE statement after a loop condition -php

Tags: php, sql

I'm trying to do a method to delete a booking from a database. How do I write the DELETE statement after the condition in the loop. I have the statement there that i want to use , but i'm just echo-ing it. I not sure how to actually put the statement into effect

```
function deleteBooking(){
        $bData = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM booking_table ORDER BY Date_of_Booking ASC");
        while($brecord = mysql_fetch_array($bData)){
            $today = date('d-m-Y');
            if($brecord['Date_of_Booking']>$today){
                echo 'DELETE * FROM booking_table WHERE Date_of_Booking <'.$today.'';
            }else{
                echo 'not deleted';
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: why not just do the deletion in one operation `> NOW()` or something, no need to select all rows

Comment: anyway maybe you mean delete all bookings from the past, then it should be less than rather than greater than `NOW()` if that's what you really want

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just do this after your condition

```
if($brecord['Date_of_Booking']>$today)
    {
       if(mysql_query("DELETE * FROM booking_table WHERE Date_of_Booking< now()")==true)
          {
            echo "delete successful";
          }
       else{
            echo "delete failed";
          }
    }
```

**NOTE:**

1. your using the depreciated mysql.
2. mysql_query() returns boolean for queries similar but not limited to (insert,update,delete)
3. I know Mine's not a good example, but as much as possible write your code in a clean manner. This makes it easier to find errors. Start with proper indention.
4. Watch when placing quotes around your string for queries.

A simple `$query = "SELECT name from Person WHERE Last_name = "John""` can cause a potential error.

Writing it this way will make it more readable and safe from syntax errors `$query = "SELECT name from Person WHERE Last_name = 'John'"` Using double and single quotes hand-in-hand

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE * FROM booking_table WHERE Date_of_Booking > NOW();
```

Answer (score -1):

You are echoing the query. You need to execute it:

```
mysql_query("DELETE * FROM booking_table WHERE Date_of_Booking <'.$today.'");
```

**Edit: Ignore the above, didn't read carefully...**

Instead:

```
mysql_query("DELETE * FROM booking_table WHERE Date_of_Booking < now()");
```

Also, mysql_query is deprecated and will be removed in the future. Therefor I recommend to use mysqli, or PDO instead.